# filter function does not return value

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I am building a movie API using Node and Express.
My filter function did not return the value,
bellow is my code so far:

```
class MovieStore{
  constructor(){
    this.movieData = require('./db/database.json');
  }
  all(){
    return this.movieData;
  }
  findMovie(tittle){
    return this.movieData.filter(movie => movie.Tittle === tittle);
  }
}
```

Is there any problem with the filter function? It returns only `[]` even if I passed the params value from URL.

This is my json:

```
 [  
   {  
      "Title":"Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2",
      "Year":"2017",
      "Rated":"PG-13",
      "Released":"05 May 2017",
      "Runtime":"136 min",
      "Genre":"Action, Adventure, Comedy",
      "Director":"James Gunn",
      "Writer":"James Gunn"
   }
]
```

Comment: hmm... is that a typo? `movie.Tittle`?

Comment: If it is a typo, you would expect all `movie.Tittle` to be `undefined`, and so the filter would return an empty array unless the argument to `findMovie` is also `undefined`.

Comment: Can you add a bit of the data from the json

Comment: this is my json file:
[{
    "Title": "Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2",
    "Year": "2017",
    "Rated": "PG-13",
    "Released": "05 May 2017",
    "Runtime": "136 min",
    "Genre": "Action, Adventure, Comedy",
    "Director": "James Gunn",
    "Writer": "James Gunn, Dan Abnett (based on the Marvel comics by),Andy 
    }
]

Comment: Can you guys explain to me what typo is? how can I check it?

Comment: @Lee0ne A typo is when you meant to type one thing, but you typed something else. For example, your object contains a `Title` property, but you instead typed `Tittle`.

Comment: @Kevin I think you're right. I have checked the title returned undefine. How can I fix that bug? Any suggest? :)

Comment: I have found my error. Thanks for helping  :)

Answer (score 0):

> My filter function did not return the value ... It returns only []

Your filter code works ok, just needs a minor typo fix (highlighted in below comment):

```js
/* define our test database */
 const inMemoryDatabase = [  
   {  
      "Title":"Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2",
      "Year":"2017",
      "Rated":"PG-13",
      "Released":"05 May 2017",
      "Runtime":"136 min",
      "Genre":"Action, Adventure, Comedy",
      "Director":"James Gunn",
      "Writer":"James Gunn"
   },
   {  
      "Title":"Pacific Rim",
      "Year":"2013",
      "Director":"Guillermo del Toro",
      "Writer":"Travis Beacham"
   }
]

/* define your class */
class MovieStore{
  constructor(){
    this.movieData = inMemoryDatabase
  }
  
  all(){
    return this.movieData;
  }
  
  findMovie(tittle){
    return this.movieData.filter(movie => movie.Title === tittle); // <- just fixed your typo here; the json database was using key "Title".
  }
}

/* create instance of your MovieStore class */
const concreteMovieStore = new MovieStore()
console.log("ALL MOVIES IN STORAGE:\n", concreteMovieStore.all())

/* test filter function */
const movie = concreteMovieStore.findMovie("Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2")
console.log("SEARCH RESULT: ", movie)
```

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
//in .db/database.json
module.exports = [{ 
  "Title":"Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2",
  "Year":"2017",
  "Rated":"PG-13",
  "Released":"05 May 2017",
  "Runtime":"136 min",
  "Genre":"Action, Adventure, Comedy",
  "Director":"James Gunn",
  "Writer":"James Gunn"
}];


const movieData  = require('./db/database.json');;
class MovieStore{
  constructor(){}
  all(){
    return movieData;
  }
  findMovie(tittle){
    return movieData.filter(movie => movie.Tittle.toLowerCase() === tittle.trim().toLowerCase());
  }
}
```

Try above code, it'll solve your problem.